# GIT Commits doesn't show login

Tags: git, authentication, ssh

When I commit my changes to GitHub repository I facing with the problem that my login doesn't show in commits history, only my name and other commit information.

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9kjo.png)

It should be like this:
[this is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em8wY.png)

Maybe it's somehow related but every time when I push the commitments it requires login and password in OpenSSH window.

Comment: GitHub provides [a helpful page](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) for setting your git username and [email address](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/) before committing.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have 2 GitHub accounts, it seems that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 2 different ssh keys. one per repository.
Github "trace" you based upon your ssh keys and you have multiple accounts.

---

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

And you all set to go :-)